# wget - How to download recursively and only specific mime-types/extensions (i.e. text only)

Tags: wget, recursive, download, mime-types

How to download a full website, but ignoring all binary files.

`wget` has this functionality using the `-r` flag but it downloads everything and some websites are just too much for a low-resources machine and it's not of a use for the specific reason I'm downloading the site.

Here is the command line i use: `wget -P 20 -r -l 0 http://www.omardo.com/blog` (my own blog)

Comment: wget can only filter with file suffix

Comment: @warl0ck I didn't know that, thanks! -A and -R options are very useful for my operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a totally different approach is to use Scrapy, however it has the same problem! Here's how I solved it: SO: [Python Scrapy - mimetype based filter to avoid non-text file downloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401382/python-scrapy-mimetype-based-filter-to-avoid-non-text-file-downloads)

> The solution is to setup a `Node.js` proxy and configure Scrapy to use
>   it through `http_proxy` environment variable.
>
> What the [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) should do is:
>
> - Take HTTP requests from Scrapy and sends it to the server being crawled. Then it gives back the response from to Scrapy i.e. intercept
>     all HTTP traffic.
> - For binary files (based on a heuristic you implement) it sends `403 Forbidden` error to Scrapy and immediate closes the request/response.
>     This helps to save time, traffic and Scrapy won't crash.
>
> #### Sample Proxy Code That actually works!

```
http.createServer(function(clientReq, clientRes) {
    var options = {
        host: clientReq.headers['host'],
        port: 80,
        path: clientReq.url,
        method: clientReq.method,
        headers: clientReq.headers
    };


    var fullUrl = clientReq.headers['host'] + clientReq.url;

    var proxyReq = http.request(options, function(proxyRes) {
        var contentType = proxyRes.headers['content-type'] || '';
        if (!contentType.startsWith('text/')) {
            proxyRes.destroy();            
            var httpForbidden = 403;
            clientRes.writeHead(httpForbidden);
            clientRes.write('Binary download is disabled.');
            clientRes.end();
        }

        clientRes.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
        proxyRes.pipe(clientRes);
    });

    proxyReq.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with clientReq: ' + e.message);
    });

    proxyReq.end();

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 28):

You could specify a list of allowed resp. disallowed filename patterns:

Allowed:

```
-A LIST
--accept LIST
```

Disallowed:

```
-R LIST
--reject LIST
```

`LIST` is comma-separated list of filename patterns/extensions.

You can use the following reserved characters to specify patterns:

- `*`
- `?`
- `[`
- `]`

Examples:

- only download PNG files: `-A png`
- don't download CSS files: `-R css`
- don't download PNG files that start with "avatar": `-R avatar*.png`

If the file has no extension resp. the file name  has no pattern you could make use of, you'd need MIME type parsing, I guess (see [Lars Kotthoffs answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53459/21962)).

Answer (score 2):

You could try patching wget with [this](http://www.larsko.org/wget) (also [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?20378)) to filter by MIME type. This patch is quite old now though, so it might not work anymore.

Comment: Giving this a shot... http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ I rolled the dice on just patching the newest version of wget with this but no luck( of course ). I would try to update the patch but I frankly don`t have the chops yet in c++ for it to not be a time sink. I did manage to grab the version of wget it was written for and get that running. I had trouble though compiling with ssl support because I could not figure out what version of openssl I needed to grab.

Comment: this looks great. any idea why this patch has not been yet accepted (four years later)?

Answer (score 2):

A new Wget (Wget2) already has feature:

```
--filter-mime-type    Specify a list of mime types to be saved or ignored`

### `--filter-mime-type=list`

Specify a comma-separated list of MIME types that will be downloaded.  Elements of list may contain wildcards.
If a MIME type starts with the character '!' it won't be downloaded, this is useful when trying to download
something with exceptions. For example, download everything except images:

  wget2 -r https://<site>/<document> --filter-mime-type=*,\!image/*

It is also useful to download files that are compatible with an application of your system. For instance,
download every file that is compatible with LibreOffice Writer from a website using the recursive mode:

  wget2 -r https://<site>/<document> --filter-mime-type=$(sed -r '/^MimeType=/!d;s/^MimeType=//;s/;/,/g' /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop)
```

Wget2 has not been released as of today, but will be soon. Debian unstable already has an alpha version shipped.

Look at https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2 for more info. You can post questions/comments directly to bug-wget@gnu.org.