# Get the file list in an HTML directory listing

Tags: bash, wget, download

I can get all files on the [bash patches site](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/) by downloading them in a sequence:

```
SEQ=$(seq -f "%03g" 1 30)
for i in $SEQ; do 
  wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-$i;
done
```

But then I would have to know the maximum number.

Is there a possibility to just get the listing and extract all patchfiles for downloading?

Comment: Why not recursively download the directory? Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118605/70524

Comment: because it is a website, How would i extract the wget links?

Comment: Something like: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53397/70524 combined with http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84017/70524

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `wget` with recursive downloading:

```
wget -nc -nd -nH -np -r -R '*.*'  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/
```

Explanation:

- `-nc`: no-clobber (don't overwrite existing files), probably not necessary.
- `-nd`: Don't create hierarchy of directories.
- `-nH`: Don't create directory based on hostname. Or you'd find everything downloaded to a directory called `ftp.gnu.org`.
- `-np`: Never ascend to the parent directory.
- `-r`: Download recursively.
- `-R '*.*'`: Reject everything with a `.` in its filename (skips things like `index.html` and so on). An accept list may also be used. [The file is downloaded, but discarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704197/wget-reject-still-downloads-file).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 999); do 
  wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-$i
  if [[ $? -ne "0" ]]; then
    MAX=$(expr $i - 1)
    break;
  fi
done
echo $MAX files downloaded
```